# CGContextFillRects: invalid context - Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this piece of code to give my images a color I need:

```
    - (UIImage*)convertToMask: (UIImage *) image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw a white background (for white mask)
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.9f);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, imageRect);

    // Apply the source image's alpha
    [image drawInRect:imageRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1.0f];

    UIImage* outImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outImage;
}
```

Everything works great in my first view but when I add this to my detail view, it gives me this error (it still works):

> CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>
> CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This
>   application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is
>   thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and
>   reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It
>   will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Any idea how to get rid of this error?

Thanks.

EDIT:

The action was called with nil for image. I easily fixed it by adding a condition. Thanks @ipmcc for the comment.

```
    - (UIImage*)convertToMask: (UIImage *) image
{

    if (image != nil) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        // Draw a white background (for white mask)
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.9f);
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, imageRect);

        // Apply the source image's alpha
        [image drawInRect:imageRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1.0f];

        UIImage* outImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return outImage;

    }else{

        return image;

    }
}
```

Comment: Third identical question in two days, second one today.

Comment: Is your image `nil`? IIRC, the context will be `nil` if you pass 0 for height, width or scale to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.

Comment: @ipmcc Yeah for some reason the method was called once with nil image. It was an easy fix by adding a condition. It worked on my first view so this didn't come to my mind. Thanks

Comment: Adding an answer to that effect for posterity and rep-whoring purposes.

Comment: If you write `convertToMask` in the category of `UIImage`, the Objective-C runtime will fix it for you, automatically. (and make more sense semantically)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:
In xcode add symbolic breakpoint to **CGPostError**. (Add symbolic breakpoint, and to Symbol field type **CGPostError**)

When error happen, debugger will stop code executions and you can check stack of methods calls and check parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
// UIImage+MyMask.h

@interface UIImage (MyMask)
- (UIImage*)convertToMask;
@end

// UIImage+MyMask.m

@implementation UIImage (MyMask)
- (UIImage*)convertToMask
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.size.width, self.size.height);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw a white background (for white mask)
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.9f);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, imageRect);

    // Apply the source image's alpha
    [image drawInRect:imageRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1.0f];

    UIImage* outImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outImage;
}
@end
```

Then you can call like this (no need to check `nil`):

```
UIImage *maskImage = [someImage convertToMask];
```

Answer (score 0):

as I know, you call UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions with a size.width or size.height 0

just  add symbolic breakpoint to CGPostError to check.